# How to make this Python class definition code less ugly

Tags: python, idioms, pyquery

What's the most idiomatic way to write a class definition? There's no way that my code below is the best way to do this.

```
class Course:

    crn =  course =  title =  tipe =  cr_hours =  seats =  instructor =  days =  begin =  end = location = exam = ""

    def __init__(self, pyQueryRow):
        self.crn = Course.get_column(pyQueryRow, 0)
        self.course = Course.get_column(pyQueryRow, 1)
        self.title = Course.get_column(pyQueryRow, 2)
        self.tipe = Course.get_column(pyQueryRow, 3)
        self.cr_hours = Course.get_column(pyQueryRow, 4)
        self.seats = Course.get_column(pyQueryRow, 5)
        self.instructor = Course.get_column(pyQueryRow, 6)
        self.days = Course.get_column(pyQueryRow, 7)
        self.begin = Course.get_column(pyQueryRow, 8)
        self.end = Course.get_column(pyQueryRow, 9)
        self.location = Course.get_column(pyQueryRow, 10)
        self.exam = Course.get_column(pyQueryRow, 11)

    def get_column(row, index):
        return row.find('td').eq(index).text()
```

[First of all python is an awesome language. This is my first project using python and I've made a ridiculous amount of progress already.]

Answer (score 15, accepted):

```
def__init__(self, pyQueryRow):
    for i,attr in enumerate("crn course title tipe cr_hours seats instructor"
                            " days begin end location exam".split()):
        setattr(self, attr, self.get_column(pyQueryRow, i))
```

This way avoids multiple calls to `self.get_column`

```
def__init__(self, pyQueryRow):
    attrs = ("crn course title tipe cr_hours seats instructor"
             " days begin end location exam".split())
    values = [td.text for td in pyQueryRow.find('td')]
    for attr, value in zip(attrs, values):
        setattr(self, attr, value)
```

Comment: Isn't this risky? What if you misspell a member in that string?

Comment: @Assaf Lavie, Same as if you mistype an attribute name in your code. Either way Python won't complain until you try to access an attribute that doesn't exist. Normally you should have unit tests that would catch those types of errors

Comment: Debatable if this looks prettier...

Answer (score 4):

Personally, I'd use a dictionary to map the property to column numbers:

```
class Course:

    crn =  course =  title =  tipe =  cr_hours =  seats =  instructor =  days =  begin =  end = location = exam = ""

    def __init__(self, pyQueryRow):
        course_row_mapping = {
            'crn' : 0,
            'course' : 1,
            'title' : 2,
            'tipe' : 3, # You probably mean "type"?
            'cr_hours' : 4,
            'seats' : 5,
            'instructor' : 6,
            'days' : 7,
            'begin' : 8,
            'end' : 9,
            'location' : 10,
            'exam' : 11,
        }   

        for name, col in course_row_mapping.iteritems():
            setattr(self, name, Course.get_column(pyQueryRow, col))

    def get_column(row, index):
        return row.find('td').eq(index).text()
```

Answer (score 2):

EDIT: Actually, the best might be:

```
self.crn, self.course, self.title, self.tipe, self.cr_hours, self.seats,\ 
self.instructor, self.days, self.begin, self.end, self.location, self.exam = \ 
[pq(td).text() for td in pyQueryRow.find('td')]
```

That assumes you've imported PyQuery as pq.  This avoids ever using indices at all.

---

```
self.crn, self.course, self.title, self.tipe, self.cr_hours, self.seats,\ 
self.instructor, self.days, self.begin, self.end, self.location, self.exam = \
map(lambda index: get_column(pyQueryRow, index), xrange(0, 12))
```

or if you want a list comprehension:

```
self.crn, self.course, self.title, self.tipe, self.cr_hours, self.seats,\ 
self.instructor, self.days, self.begin, self.end, self.location, self.exam = \
[get_column(pyQueryRow, index) for index in xrange(0, 12)]
```

I don't know if these are the most idiomatic, but there's definitely less boilerplate.

Also, remove the `crn = course =`.  You're assigning to the class, not the instance.

Comment: Yeah I thought about a similar solution but not quite as elegant as yours (list comprehension instead of map (which is dumb when you consider map is defined in terms of a list comprehension)).

Comment: I like the lambda idea, but I don't think this is actually more readable, because it's hard to see which index gets mapped to which field. Imagine if you had to add one in the middle somewhere - it would be easy to make a mistake.

Comment: @Evgeny, I see what you mean.  But since it's based on scraping an HTML page, if one is added in the middle, the others will shift down. You just have to put it between the correct two and increment the maximum.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure that there is a "better" way. What you have is certainly quite readable. If you wanted to avoid duplicating the `Course.get_column` code you could define a lambda for that, as in Matthew Flaschen's answer, eg.

```
class Course:
    def __init__(self, pyQueryRow):
        get_column = lambda index: pyQueryRow.find('td').eq(index).text()

        self.crn = get_column(0)
        self.course = get_column(1)
        self.title = get_column(2)
        self.tipe = get_column(3)
        self.cr_hours = get_column(4)
        self.seats = get_column(5)
        self.instructor = get_column(6)
        self.days = get_column(7)
        self.begin = get_column(8)
        self.end = get_column(9)
        self.location = get_column(10)
        self.exam = get_column(11)
```

Note that you don't need the line that initialises all the fields to "" beforehand - just setting them in `__init__` is fine. **Edit:** in fact, as Matthew says, that sets class fields, not instance fields - I totally missed that.

Answer (score 0):

Personally I feel a class shouldn't really know about the outside world. So move it all out and your class looks much prettier. And also more reusable.

```
class Course:

    def __init__(
            self,
            crn="",
            course="",
            title="",
            tipe="",
            cr_hours="",
            seats="",
            instructor="",
            days="",
            begin="",
            end="",
            location="",
            exam=""
    ):
        self.crn = crn
        self.course = course
        self.title = title
        self.tipe = tipe
        self.cr_hours = cr_hours
        self.seats = seats
        self.instructor = instructor
        self.days = days
        self.begin = begin
        self.end = end
        self.location = location
        self.exam = exam


def course_from_row(row):
    column_mapping = {
        'crn': 0,
        'course': 1,
        'title': 2,
        'tipe': 3,
        'cr_hours': 4,
        'seats': 5,
        'instructor': 6,
        'days': 7,
        'begin': 8,
        'end': 9,
        'location': 10,
        'exam': 11
    }

    course = {}
    for attr, col in column_mapping.items():
        course[attr] = row.find('td').eq(col).text()

    return Course(**course)
```